# python on an AWS m6g instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, arm

I am trying to install a reasonable python 3 on an AWS m6g instance - this is their latest and greatest, and therein lies the rub. It is an ARM64 box, so there is no anaconda install for that (that I know of). I am installing packages manually via pip3, and after much loading of the requisite system packages, compilers, and so on, things mostly work WITH THE EXCEPTION OF matplotlib, which comes up with (sorry, don't know how to indent all of the below four spaces). Any ideas?

```
    pip3 install matplotlib --user
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/4b/06f4aa9bef6b5e4f177881b4dedd94faa6e7cb3d95dfaeaa8a1a8b541095/matplotlib-3.2.2.tar.gz
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/d2/e07d3ebb2bd7af696440ce7e754c59dd546ffe1bbe732c8ab68b9c834e61/cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/b8/db619d97819afb52a3ff5ff6ad3f7de408cc83a8ec2dfb31a1731c0a97c2/kiwisolver-1.2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs/source'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.git'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'dist'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-c8bpoixa/cppy-1.1.0/setup.py", line 24, in <module>
        'py/solver.cpp',
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 218, in run
        os.path.join(archive_root, 'EGG-INFO'), self.zip_safe()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 269, in zip_safe
        return analyze_egg(self.bdist_dir, self.stubs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 379, in analyze_egg
        safe = scan_module(egg_dir, base, name, stubs) and safe
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 416, in scan_module
        code = marshal.load(f)
    ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-6x1f9zgp/kiwisolver/setup.py", line 80, in <module>
        cmdclass={'build_ext': BuildExt},
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 461, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 866, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1146, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1158, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 528, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 672, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 698, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 881, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1149, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1135, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/tmp/easy_install-c8bpoixa/cppy-1.1.0/setup.py", line 24, in <module>
        'py/solver.cpp',
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 218, in run
        os.path.join(archive_root, 'EGG-INFO'), self.zip_safe()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 269, in zip_safe
        return analyze_egg(self.bdist_dir, self.stubs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 379, in analyze_egg
        safe = scan_module(egg_dir, base, name, stubs) and safe
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 416, in scan_module
        code = marshal.load(f)
    ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-6x1f9zgp/kiwisolver/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-71-160 bin]$
```

Answer (score 2):

Many of the dependencies of `matplotlib` have had new `aarch64` wheels uploaded to pypi.org in the last few months since you posted this question. `matplotlib` itself doesn't have an `aarch64` wheel available yet, but recently a [change was merged](https://github.com/MacPython/matplotlib-wheels/pull/12) to build one, so it probably will have one available soon. Even though `matplotlib` doesn't have a binary wheel published yet, I was able to install it on Ubuntu 20.04. It takes a minute or two to build, but it works:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

For completeness, I was able to get a full suite of python data science packages installed on Ubuntu 20.04 Arm with the following Dockerfile. (Just run the `apt` and `pip` commands if you aren't using Docker.) It takes a long time to complete since it builds many of these packages from source.

As more python packages begin publishing `aarch64` wheels, this should become obsolete.

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        python3-pip \
        python3-dev \
        libfreetype-dev \
        libopenblas64-dev \
        mklibs \
        libmlpack-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
        liblapack64-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        gfortran

RUN pip3 install jupyterlab matplotlib numpy pandas seaborn
```

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful! Hopefully the anaconda people are at least somewhat on the ball as well...